# Site Search Options for LAMP Website

Tags: search

I'm looking for some suggestions from search experts.  I want to implement site search and don't really know where to start.  What are the pros and cons of the various search technologies for a PHP / MySQL website?

Answer (score 0):

For many websites, I've been using Solr. Solr is a great search server platform. It requires Tomcat and some configurations but it's built by Apache so it's pretty easy to get going.

Take a look : http://lucene.apache.org/solr/